# write file using WScript.shell

Tags: javascript, scripting, windows-shell, jscript

How can I write text files using WScript I'm really new on this that's why I cannot give some details. I want to write a log file that can be stored in c://users/user/appdata/local

my sample code, using FileSystemObject

```
function WriteFile() 
{
   var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
   var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("d:\\Test.txt", true); 
   fh.WriteLine("Some text goes here..."); 
   fh.Close(); 
}

<body onload = "WriteFile();">
</body>
```

it does return in d: but in local c: it wont.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create and write text file on C hardrive using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461331/create-and-write-text-file-on-c-hardrive-using-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing one important parameter in `fh`. The right code is:

```
var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("d:\\Test.txt", 2, true);
```

whereas `2` is a bytecode, which tells to `fso` to write a file. For reading value is 1, and for appending value is 8.

This is clear to you by now, I suppose.